# Android ScrollView not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have solved my question. I chose to instead have a header and a footer that are always located at the bottom and top of the screen respectively. Then I created a "center content" which I enclosed within a ScrollView layout. I have updated the code below if people are interested in seeing what it now looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@layout/header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/header">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dip" >
            <!--  Email Label -->
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372C24"
                android:text="@string/email"/>
            <EditText android:id="@+id/email_field"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
            <!--  Password Label -->
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:textColor="#372C24"
                android:text="@string/password"/>
            <EditText android:id="@+id/password_field"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>
            <!-- Login button -->
            <Button android:id="@+id/login_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
                android:text="@string/login"/>
            <!-- Register button -->
            <Button android:id="@+id/register_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
                android:text="@string/register_button"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dip"
        android:background="@layout/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed this line from the AndroidManifest.xml file

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

and added this line

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`

it has both fixed my scrolling app and made my app look more visually appealing. However, I am not sure if this is the correct fix.

Answer (score 5):

For me, remove `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` of the `<activity>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file solved the problem.

Comment: I wonder what is the alternative if I want to use the above attribute!

Answer (score -1):

for me the problem was that the LinearLayout  in the ScrowView had android:layout_height="wrap_content".

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll_view1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_inside"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" --> This should not we wrap_content, but specific height.
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: According to Android guidelines, `android:layout_height` attribute of the first (and only) ScrollView children should always be "`wrap_content`". You will get a Lint warning if you use match_parent.

Answer (score -2):

The ScrollView is not working when used as the root element of an XML layout. 
It has to be wrapped inside a LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_inside"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Have a fun ! !

Answer (score -4):

ScrollView must have Linearlayout control as a immediate child, you have relative layout, I think that might be causing the problem.

Check [this](http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/02/scrollview-tutorial-android-ui.html) link out, also [this](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/). Look at their layout xmls..

Comment: Its not true. you can have any, but only one child in scrollview

Comment: Scroll views ARE NOT required to have a LinearLayout as their immediate child. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html