# Android: Scrollview doesn't scroll anymore

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a scrollview which was scrolling fine, until I added elements inside and it stopped scrolling. I tried many things, including changing the height to fill_parent or wrap_content, but somehow I cannot find which value is blocking the scroll. Anyone can help? Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/bg_layout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
android:background="@drawable/detail_background"
tools:context="com.kalianey.oxapp.views.fragments.ProfileFragment">

    <com.kalianey.oxapp.utils.UIParallaxScroll //extends ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:headerView="@+id/layout_top">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:id="@+id/cover_container">

            <com.kalianey.oxapp.utils.UICircularImage
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                app:line_color="@android:color/white"
                app:line_color_press="@color/theme_color"
                app:line_width="1dp"
                app:padding="0dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:text="@string/detail_title_placeholder"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_xlarge"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sumary"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:text="@string/sumary_placeholder"
                android:textColor="@color/white_transparent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium_small" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/statistics"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sumary"
                android:background="@color/gray_transparent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_right" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonFriend"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/user"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/gray_transparent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonFavorite"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/star"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/informations_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cover_container"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <com.kalianey.oxapp.utils.UITabs
                android:id="@+id/toggle"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@+id/informations_container">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/toggle1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="@string/description_tab_1"
                    style="@style/UITabs" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/toggle2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/description_tab_2"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    style="@style/UITabs" />

            </com.kalianey.oxapp.utils.UITabs>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/profile_photo_text"
                android:text="@string/profile_photo_text"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noPhotos"
                android:layout_below="@+id/profile_photo_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/noPhotos"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_light"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium_small"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:height="70dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
              android:id="@+id/grid_view"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="250dp"
              app:layoutManager="StaggeredGridLayoutManager"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/profile_friend_text"
                android:text="@string/profile_friend_text"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noFriends"
                android:layout_below="@+id/profile_friend_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/noFriends"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_light"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium_small"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/friends_list"
                style="@style/TwoWayView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

            <se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
                android:id="@+id/questions_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</com.kalianey.oxapp.utils.UIParallaxScroll>

<!-- "ActionBar"  -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nesting scrolling `View`s - like `RecyclerView`s or `ListView`s - in a regular `ScrollView` always causes problems. If you have access to the source for `UIParallaxScroll`, you might try refactoring it to use [`NestedScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) from the v4 support library. Or change your design to move those scrolling `View`s elsewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076195/android-scrollview-not-scrolling.

Comment: @MikeM.: So I changed to NestedScrollView and the result is very weird: on the simulator and on a phone now it's working fine (thanks by the way!), but on tablet it still doesn't scroll... Any idea why?

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. I can't think of any reason why, off the top of my head. I've not done any UIs for tablets, but I would think it should work just as well there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below xml code which will help you to to build screen with scrolling even though it contains recycler view.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text=" " />
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rcy1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        android:numColumns="4"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                        android:padding="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rcy2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="300dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:numColumns="3"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                        android:padding="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You can use elements that you wanted in this.Also you may change the base CoordinatorLayout to LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.Also don't forget to add the below supports in dependencies section in your build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```